# assigning resources in Activit and esper engines

Tags: activiti, esper

I am trying to modify a code that detect events from activiti engine and throw them on ESPER stream and try to map and change variables of them and throw new events on the same stream. in order to do that I created a named window to throw all events detected from Activiti into it

```
epAdmin.createEPL("create window intermwindow.win:keepall() as select taskInstanceId,receiveTime,requestedAmount,eventType from tasklistenerlogic", "cepStatementmainquerywindow"); //create a new named window 

epAdmin.createEPL("insert into intermwindow(taskInstanceId, receiveTime, requestedAmount, eventType ) select taskInstanceId,receiveTime,requestedAmount,'created' from tasklistenerlogic where eventType = 'create' ", "cepStatementmainquerywindowii1");

epAdmin.createEPL("insert into intermwindow(taskInstanceId, receiveTime, requestedAmount, eventType ) select taskInstanceId,receiveTime,requestedAmount,'allocated' from tasklistenerlogic where eventType = 'assignment' ", "cepStatementmainquerywindowii2");

epAdmin.createEPL("insert into intermwindow(taskInstanceId, receiveTime, requestedAmount, eventType) select taskInstanceId,receiveTime,requestedAmount,'completed' from tasklistenerlogic where eventType = 'complete' ", "cepStatementmainquerywindowii3");

epAdmin.createEPL("select * from intermwindow", "cepStatementmainquerywindowo");
```

all I need to do is assign multiple resources to the same task as stated below

```
taskService.setAssignee(taskService.createTaskQuery().singleResult().getId(),"Atef");

taskService.setAssignee(taskService.createTaskQuery().singleResult().getId(),"Ramadan");
```

this is the output I got:

```
>>> Throwing event: task  assignment  successfully: LoanRequestReceivedEvent{taskInstanceId= 9,receiveTime= 1446853025179,requestedAmount= 10,eventtype= assignment,resource= Atef}
event mapped successfully:  {receiveTime=1446853025179, requestedAmount=10, taskInstanceId=9, eventType=allocated}
>>> Throwing event: task  assignment  successfully: LoanRequestReceivedEvent{taskInstanceId= 9,receiveTime= 1446853025226,requestedAmount= 10,eventtype= assignment,resource= Ramadan}
event mapped successfully:  {receiveTime=1446853025226, requestedAmount=10, taskInstanceId=9, eventType=allocated}
```

the problem is whenever I tried to write a query to get all the different resources for the same taskID like this

```
epAdmin.createEPL("select * from pattern [ every tasklistenerlogic(resource = \"Atef\") -> tasklistenerlogic(resource = \"Ramadan\") ]", "q3");
```

this error appears:
Tests in error:

```
testEsperActivitiSetup(org.bpmnwithactiviti.chapter14.LoanRequestProcessWithEsperTest): Property named 'resource' is not valid in any stream [select * from pattern [ every tasklistenerlogic(resource = "Atef") -> tasklistenerlogic(resource = "Ramadan") ]]
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe try a "select * from tasklistenerlogic" to see if the output includes a "resource" field.

Comment: when I wrote this query to detect the problem   epAdmin.createEPL("select * from  tasklistenerlogic", "q3"); the listener runs only when the task completed